# Rails 4 lambda route request.session not yet loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lambda, routes

I'm having trouble trying to access the request session in one of my route constraints.  I've used something like this in Rails 3 before and I've seen tutorials using something similar on other sites as well.  For some reason though in Rails 4 this no longer works.  Do I have to make adjustments to the middle ware loading?

config/routes.rb

```
admin_constraint = lambda do |request|
  request.session[:user_id] == 1
end
```

Exception that is raised:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x7fc878b35400 not yet loaded>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in order to get this working I had to set a value to the session first.  Updated example code as follows:

```
admin_constraint = lambda do |request|
  request.session[:init] = true # Starts up the session so we can access values from it later.
  request.session[:user_id] == 1
end
```

From here you can do other things like load a user record from the db given the session :user_id, etc.